# Gitlab CE Server Error Recofigure Centos 7

Tags: gitlab-ce

i just got an error when i run **gitlab-ctl reconfigure** on centos 7. This is my error message :

```
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

rails_migration[gitlab-rails] (gitlab::database_migrations line 51) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: bash[migrate gitlab-rails database] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/resources/rails_migration.rb line 16) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20210712-28268-148jop5" ----
STDOUT: rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:db:configure
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
STDERR:
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20210712-28268-148jop5" ----
Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20210712-28268-148jop5" returned 1
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: did you get any solution?. am facing the same issue.

Comment: no i don't, sadly. i just remove and reinstall it